# VIM and taglist stick to file when opening

Tags: vim, taglist

I already have `taglist` working well. When I press the binding for the `toggle` it stays focused in the main file. But how do I force to keep the focus in the file when opening?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the plugin's documentation (`:help taglist-using`), this behavior is determined by a configuration variable:

```
:let g:Tlist_GainFocus_On_ToggleOpen = 1
```